# Open File in Default Viewer From Python on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, process, launch, viewer

It is a common usecase to launch a file from a Python script to view the output file in a graphical viewer and let the python script finish without closing the viewer. On Linux xdg based systems like Ubuntu, you simply use `os.system(f'xdg-open "{file}"')`. However on windows, that does not work.

On Windows, people recommend using the `start` command but this requires calling through `cmd.exe` like `os.system(f'cmd /k start "{file}"')`. This  will still bind the opened process to the python's process whereas when the Python process ends, the launched viewer window is closed.

How would one launch a default viewer in Windows for a file, for instance a PDF Viewer, and allow the python script to exit while keeping PDF Viewer open?

Please only provide Python 3x compatible options.

Answer (score 0):

Explorer can be used as a launcher for the default viewer of a file. When used on combination with subprocess.Popen and DETACHED_PROCESS flag, the opened window will stay open even after the Python script exits.

```py
import subprocess
out_file = "c:\some\path\file.pdf"
subprocess.Popen(["explorer", out_file],
      creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS)
```

Notes:

- Ensure that `out_file` is a windows compatible path.
- `subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS` is a `Windows` only feature

Comment: Using Explorer like this does work but it is only documented to support opening folders, ShellExecute on files could stop working in the future...